# Python: Select subset with logical operations based on regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to select a subset from my dataframe with two logical operations:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'location')
print(df)
ns = df[(df.season == 'winter 2020/2021') & (df.booking == '^C.*')]
print(ns)
```

with this .csv file:

```
season,booking
winter 2020/2021,C123
winter 2019/2020,C234
winter 2020/2021,B123
winter 2020/2021,E147
```

I expect this result:

```
season,booking
winter 2020/2021,C123
```

The console gave me this result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [season, booking]
Index: []
```

I think it has something to do with my 2nd logical operation. How can i write the right regex to get the desired result?

Comment: This string comparison does not use regex. You are looking for strings that are exactly '^C.*' and there are no such lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) method:

```
# method 1
df.loc[(df.season == 'winter 2020/2021') & (df.booking.str.startswith('C'))]

# method 2
df.loc[(df.season == 'winter 2020/2021') & (df.booking.str.contains('^C'))]

             season booking
0  winter 2020/2021    C123
```

Comment: Notice that str.contains has an option for turning regex on or off. The default behavior is to use regex. Method 2 above is equivalent to `df.booking.str.contains('^C', regex=True)`.